# array length undefined with base64 encode

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="question_set"><img class="centre" id="question" src=""></div>

<script>
var questionImages = [  "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS..."
];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < questionImages.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById("question").src = questionImages[i];
        }, 1500);
    }
}, false);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The website basically switch photos with a timeout.
When I use document.getElementById("question").src = questionImages[0];,
I am ok to set the pictures.
But when i use for loop with array.length,
it shows error: file not found in console

Is the base64 encode to long?

Comment: Can you post the full base64 encoded string please? It may be something in there; like an apostrophe.

Comment: Seems the encoded images are wrong

Comment: Note that all timeout callbacks will execute simultaneously after 1.5 sec. You need to multiply `1500` with `i + 1`

Comment: can you post result in console : `questionImages.length` ?

Comment: to @JamesElliott
it is too long to post here.
But like what i have said, i can call the picture in an other way

Comment: @BobSponge That's obviously true. I oversee that the timeout is set and the loop continue.

Comment: @Kelvin It turns out questionImages.length can be shown

Comment: everything you code in javascript file is possible run in browser console. So can you show me `questionImages.length` when you type it to console and press `Enter`?

Comment: @Kelvin In my case, i first used one base64 only and it is 1 in console. Then I add another one and it is 2 in console

Comment: @user3042713 can you edit your code with `getElementById("question_set")`

Answer (score 0):

the value of variable 'i' changes by the time the setimeout executes. One way is to restructure the code as below. Change the DOMContentLoaded to whenever you want to run the code.

```
var questionImages = [  "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS..."
], i=0, interval;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  interval = setInterval(update,1500);
}, false);

function update(){
    if(i<questionImages.length)
        document.getElementById("question").src = questionImages[i++];
    else
        clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Comment: What I still do not understand is the var i is in the for-loop scope and questionImages[i] accesses the var i within the scope relating to global array questiomImages.

Comment: As you have used closures.. its not a scope issue, when the timeout is schedule it keeps the variable as reference and not value. 
So by the time the timeout triggers, value of 'i' is 1, as it has updated with next iteration of for loop. And the timeout function now reads 'i' as 1.